# Facebook Connect - JavaScript and PHP SDK

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I tried to combine these two SDKs. In order to do that, I created this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>New JavaScript SDK & OAuth 2.0 based FBConnect Tutorial | Thinkdiff.net</title>
        <!--
            @author: Mahmud Ahsan (http://mahmud.thinkdiff.net)
        -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var button;
            var userInfo;

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxxx', //change the appId to your appId
                    status: true,
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    oauth: true});
                showLoader(true);

        </script>

        <body>
            <?php
                $cookie = preg_replace("/^\"|\"$/i", "", $_COOKIE['fbs_' . "203222769784206"]);
                parse_str($cookie, $data);

                $fb = new Facebook(array(
                    'appId'  => "xxxx",
                    'secret' => "xxxxxx"
                ));
                $fb->setAccessToken($data['access_token']);
                var_dump($fb->getUser());
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, it prints int(0). What might be the problem? Where is it wrong? Is there a problem with access tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code won't work. Here is the problem - PHP code is run on server side and JS/HTML code is run on browser. You are running a PHP server-side code which depends on something that will happen only after the page is loaded and run. It might be able to work the next pageview, since the cookie might be set.

Also, the access_token thing may not be set until the user authorizes the app. Have you checked for that?

That said, this is a very poor way of getting the user's data. Parsing a cookie set by FB is not a FB supported way of doing it and may violate API's terms and conditions.

You must perhaps use the standard JS-SDK [FB.Login()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) to log users in and get the access_token and send it to the server and get the data on the server side.